# ng command is not recognized in any cmd

Tags: npm, path, angular-cli

I needed to uninstall and reinstall angular, I did so and force cleared the cache as recommended, and reinstalled. Similarly, I uninstalled NodeJS and removed any remaining files after installation. I have reinstalled both - but the ng command is not recognised. I have added the paths to the environment variables (see picture) and rebooted my PC, but is still unrecognised in both the windows cmd and node.js cmd. I have also tried 'npm run ng ' and 'npm start ng '. I have tried everything so hopefully someone can help me out! Thanks
[image]

edit: the ng command worked fine before first uninstallation

Comment: npm install -g @angular/cli Did you do that? Close and reopen cmd

Comment: Hi Walter thanks for the response, I have done that (and rebooted) but still no joy.